# Pandas calculate sum of each row with row before

Tags: python, pandas

or how to calculate an account balance for each booking.

I have a dataframe for each transaction on account where the amount of the transaction is just a positive or negative number in the column. Additionally I have the current account balance.

What I want to do is to add a `balance` column to my data frame where to current balance after each booking is stored.

```
                            amount
bookingDate                        
2016-10-25 00:00:00+00:00   8424.09
2016-10-26 00:00:00+00:00  -3264.72
2016-10-27 00:00:00+00:00    -27.50
2016-10-28 00:00:00+00:00   -611.85
2016-10-31 00:00:00+00:00   -248.40
2016-11-01 00:00:00+00:00   323.37
```

Let's say balance at `2016-10-25` (after +8424.09) is `5000` so I expect something like:

```
                            amount     balance
bookingDate    
2016-10-25 00:00:00+00:00   8424.09    5000
2016-10-26 00:00:00+00:00  -3264.72    1735.28
2016-10-27 00:00:00+00:00    -27.50    1707.78
2016-10-28 00:00:00+00:00   -611.85    1095.93
2016-10-31 00:00:00+00:00   -248.40     847.53
2016-11-01 00:00:00+00:00    323.37    1170.90
```

What would be the best way to do so in pandas? How can I take into account having variable start amounts for the account balance?

Comment: @jpp thanks, fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), add your starting balance and deduct the initial amount:

```
df['Balance'] = df['amount'].cumsum() + 5e3 - df['amount'].iloc[0]

print(df)

              amount  Balance
bookingDate                  
2016-10-25   8424.09  5000.00
2016-10-26  -3264.72  1735.28
2016-10-27    -27.50  1707.78
2016-10-28   -611.85  1095.93
2016-10-31   -248.40   847.53
2016-11-01   -323.37   524.16
```

Comment: neat and well thought

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `balance` as the `amount` column except for the starting balance and then perform [`cumsum()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html).

**One liner**:

```
df['balance'] = pd.Series([5000], index=[0]).append(df['amount'][1:]).cumsum()
```

**Longer and easy to understand version**:

```
df['balance'] = df['amount']
df.loc[0, 'balance'] = 5000
df['balance'] = df['balance'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
                 bookingDate   amount  balance
0  2016-10-25 00:00:00+00:00  8424.09  5000.00
1  2016-10-26 00:00:00+00:00 -3264.72  1735.28
2  2016-10-27 00:00:00+00:00   -27.50  1707.78
3  2016-10-28 00:00:00+00:00  -611.85  1095.93
4  2016-10-31 00:00:00+00:00  -248.40   847.53
5  2016-11-01 00:00:00+00:00  -323.37   524.16
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [`DataFrame.cumsum()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html).

Comment: In my opinion, this should be a comment rather than an answer :).